# Android getDrawable in Extended ImageView returns always the original drawable

Tags: android, imageview, android-canvas, android-drawable, android-bitmap

I've extended an ImageView and i've added a line to the canvas in the onDraw method.

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { 

    if(mBitmap!=null) {

        paint.reset();
        paint.setXfermode(DUFF_LIGHTEN);
        paint.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
        paint.setStrokeWidth(30);

        canvas.drawLine(0, 100, canvas.getWidth(), 100, paint);     

    }       
}
```

I can see the line on the screen but when i call the GetDrawable Method i get the original image.
UI Canvas (the onDraw one) can't be assigned to another bitmap. This throws an unsupportedoperationexception.

How should i override the getDrawable method to get the image drawed in the screen canvas?

```
@Override
public Drawable getDrawable() {
    return super.getDrawable();
}
```

I can't use getDrawingCache becouse my image is bigger then screen.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get Drawable with line you shoud draw on Drawable canvas (convert to bitmap and draw) not on ImageView canvas. Drawing on ImageView canvas not draw on Drawable stored in variable.